# Python syntax error (ELIF) that i can't recognize

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
score = float(input("Score: "))
if score >= 0 and score <= 1.0:
    elif score >= 0.9:
        print("A")
    elif score >= 0.8:
        print("B")
    elif score >= 0.7:
        print("C")
    elif score >= 0.6:
         print("D")
    elif score < 0.6:
         print("F")
else: 
    print("Bad Score")
```

Tried to run this simple code but the output is giving me a syntax error that i can't recognize.

Output:

```
File C:\Python\Aprendizado 2 (PY for Everybody)\2.15.7.py", line 3
    elif score >= 0.9:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: "elif" should be "if" in that line. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] if you want advice.

Comment: The `elif` has no matching `if`, and is therefore illegal.

Comment: Thankyou so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you're inside an `if` block you need to define another `if` condition in it and only then you can access `elif` otherwise it will error out because you're trying to refer to an `if` that is not in scope of the block.

```
score = float(input("Score: "))

if score >= 0 and score <= 1.0:
    if score >= 0.9:
        print("A")
    elif score >= 0.8:
        print("B")
    elif score >= 0.7:
        print("C")
    elif score >= 0.6:
         print("D")
    elif score < 0.6:
         print("F")
else: 
    print("Bad Score")
```

Comment: KKKKKKK i think not, im liking python so much.

Comment: Reading a lot of books etc

Comment: which books u used to study?